# App was rejected for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy and software that contains security vulnerabilities

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, android-security, trustmanager, x509trustmanager

I have updated the app and it got rejected by play store saying

"We rejected Your App, with package name XYZ, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure."

For this i have removed the line on code from Manifest file "cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"" and again tried to push the app to play store but still it is being rejected with same reason

For more information i have recently added following libray files in gradle file

```
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
implementation 'com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
```

Here are the premission i have added recently in manifest file :

```
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Also there mentioned like : TrustManager
You can find more information about TrustManager in this Google Help Center article.
Can you please help me out to fix this issue, thank you

Comment: target sdk?....

Comment: maybe is system alert window permission: read here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW. Plus: you must provide an in-app privacy policy

Comment: @PhantomLord target sdk is 29

Comment: User data policy: check your app name and icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a code related to trust manager, i have commented code and pushed to play store it has worked

Comment: Can you point what code exactly did you comment?